# MVC Web Api call from Ajax responds with 404

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404

I know this has been asked dozens of times but I'm really frustrated as none of the suggestions I can find out there work for me and I'm really stuck.

My problem is I'm not being able to call a Web Api from ajax, no matter what configurations/combinations/whatever of routes and everything I try, none of them works and I just get 404.

This is my Global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
```

This is my WebApiConfig.cs in App_Start folder:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

This is my UserController class:

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult GetUserDataById(string id)
    {
        Clients jsonData = Http.downloadJsonData<Clients>(InsuranceGlobal.clientsUrl);
        Client user = jsonData.clients.Where(u => u.id == id).FirstOrDefault();

        return Ok(user);
    }
}
```

This is my Ajax call inside cshtml javascript section:

```
$("#btnGetUserById").click(function () {
        $('#userByName').empty();
        $("#gettingByIdMsg").text(" Getting User...");
        $.ajax({
            url: '../api/User',
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { id: $("#userId").val() },
            success: function (data) {
                $('<tr>', { html: formatItem(data) }).appendTo($('#userByName'));
                $("#usersTable").removeClass("hidden");
                $("#gettingByIdMsg").text("");
            },
            fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                $("#gettingByIdMsg").text("Request failed: " + textStatus);
            }
        });
    });
```

I tried GET as well as POST with the [HttpPost] decorator with no avail.

I guess I have all necessary Web Api NuGet packages installed and the app compiles without errors but web api is not being called.

Please help.

Edit 1:

[image]

I have to mention that -on purpose- I haven't started a new project with WebApi template in Visual Studio, instead I started a MVC project and then installed all NuGet WebApi necessary packages and configuration (maybe I missed something, don't know).

Comment: the api is not defined so you get 404 not found..  Change api method name to `Get(string id)` or decorate your api with `[Route("getbyId")]` and change your client to use `/api/user/getbyId` as you have `MapAttributeRoutes`

Comment: I almost tried all the possibilities .but dint find any issue with this code .May be you can clean and rebuild the solution.it happened with me many times that with the same route I was getting 404 first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after solving my issue I'll answer my own question.

First of all I have to say thanks for all the replies. Love this community and people is very nice here.

After diving into depths of sea... err my solution configuration and fighting a lot with it I remembered I've previously installed WebApi.Owin package and just to try I decided to uninstall it leaving only AspNet.WebApi and voilá, now the WebApi calls are working.

I hope all this effort will help anyone else having a similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Change 
EDIT: based on comment

```
[RoutePrefix("api/User")]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    [Route("getbyid/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUserDataById(string id)
    {
        Clients jsonData = Http.downloadJsonData<Clients> InsuranceGlobal.clientsUrl);
        Client user = jsonData.clients.Where(u => u.id == 
id).FirstOrDefault();

        return Ok(user);
    }
}
```

and client  to

```
$("#btnGetUserById").click(function () {
        $('#userByName').empty();
        $("#gettingByIdMsg").text(" Getting User...");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/User/getbyid/' + id: $("#userId").val(),
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                $('<tr>', { html: formatItem(data) }).appendTo($('#userByName'));
                $("#usersTable").removeClass("hidden");
                $("#gettingByIdMsg").text("");
            },
            fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                $("#gettingByIdMsg").text("Request failed: " + textStatus);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: you have missed out a '/' before Id parameter

Comment: in the client side you missed that.But you need to figure out why the posted code dint work though.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I modified header of method as suggested: [Route("getbyid/{id}")] and changed url according to suggestions too but the same result, nothing happens.

If I check Network Tab in firefox I see the url as http://localhost:52013/api/User/getbyid/?id=e8fd159b-57c4-4d36-9bd7-a59ca13057bb and with a 404.

Comment: I forgot to add the `RoutePrefix` at the controller level.

Comment: See my edits Nilesh please.
My conclussion is as I've added all necessary WebApi NuGet packages after creating the solution and not with the template maybe I missed something. I have the WebApi.Owin and the AspNet.WebApi and required dependencies but maybe something is missing. I cannot figure out.

Comment: You might want to remove the ‘..‘ before the ‘/‘ in the url from the client.